# css div from one position to another

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to do an image hover effect in which a link move from top:0 to top:40%.The problem is that the link appear directly on top:40% when I hover the image.  This is my code:

```
<div class="featured">
<div class="img-hover">
<a href=""><i></i></a>
</div>
<img src=""/>
</div>

.featured .img-hover {
width:100%;
float:left;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
display:none;
background:rgba(26, 188, 156, 0.6);
}

.featured:hover .img-hover {
display:block;
}

.featured .img-hover a{
width:50px;
height:50px;
float:left;
position:absolute;
top:0;
font-size:2rem;
line-height: 4rem;
opacity:1;
margin-right:20px;
border-radius:50px;
border:2px solid #fff;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.featured:hover .img-hover a{
top:40%;
}
```

Comment: Where is your markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your transition is on the *a* tag, it works better on just the ".featured .img-hover" level.  Also, the transition of the "display:none" wasn't working well.  I updated it to transition from opacity 0 to 1, and it looks better.  Below is the JSFiddle and minorly updated CSS.  Take a look and tweak if you'd like.

http://jsfiddle.net/UVjFz/

```
.featured .img-hover {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
    background:rgba(26, 188, 156, 0.6);
}

.featured:hover .img-hover {
    display:block;
}

.featured .img-hover a{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    font-size:2rem;
    line-height: 4rem;
    opacity:1;
    margin-right:20px;
    border-radius:50px;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.featured:hover .img-hover a{
    top:40%;
}

.featured:hover .img-hover {
    display:block;
    opacity:1;
}

.featured .img-hover {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;  
}
```